# get all contacts from Netsuite using Suitetalk and Java?

Tags: netsuite

How to retrieved all contacts from Netsuite. I am using Java and Netsuite Suitetalk.

I tried all methods in Netsuite, but nothing returning all contacts from Netsuite

Comment: What exactly is going wrong? What errors are you seeing? Some code samples of what you have tried will help. When you say "all", do you mean "all active" or "all, active and inactive"?

Comment: I tried some random operations, not sure if that's the way of doing it. But it's not returning any contacts

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `ContactSearchBasic`.  I added one filter to exclude inactive records but if you want those just strip that out.  Sample is C# but you should get the idea.

```
        ContactSearchBasic contactSearchBasic = new ContactSearchBasic();
        contactSearchBasic.isInactive = new SearchBooleanField();
        contactSearchBasic.isInactive.searchValue = false;
        contactSearchBasic.isInactive.searchValueSpecified = true;

        SearchResult searchResult = _service.search(contactSearchBasic);
        if (searchResult.status.isSuccess)
        {
            foreach (Record contactRecord in searchResult.recordList)
            {
                if (contactRecord is Contact)
                {
                    Contact contact = (Contact)(contactRecord);
                    //do something with the contact record
                }
            }
        }
```